# React component not rendering at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here's the code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const FilterLengthZero = ({ setEmptyDetailedCountry }) => {
  useEffect(() => setEmptyDetailedCountry(), [])
  return <div>Type to search</div>
}

const FilterLengthNine = ({ setEmptyDetailedCountry }) => {
  useEffect(() => setEmptyDetailedCountry(), [])
  return <div>Too many matches. Type more!</div>
}

const FilterLengthGreaterThanOne = ({ filteredCountries, buttonHandler }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        filteredCountries.map(country => (
          <CountryButton key={country.name.common} country={country} onClick={() => buttonHandler(country)} />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const FilterLengthEqualToOne = ({ filteredCountries, setActualDetailedCountry }) => {
  useEffect(() => setActualDetailedCountry(filteredCountries[0]), [])
}

const Display = ({ country }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Country</h2>
      <div>Capital {country.capital}</div>
      <div>Area {country.area}</div>
      <h3>Languages</h3>
      <ul>
        {Object.values(country.languages).map(language => (
          <li key={language}>{language}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <img src={country.flags.png} />
    </div>
  );
};

const CountryButton = ({ country, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {country.name.common}
      <button onClick={() => onClick(country)}>show</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const CheckConditions = ({ setEmptyDetailedCountry, filteredCountries, filter, buttonHandler, setActualDetailedCountry }) => {
  if (filter === '') {
    return <FilterLengthZero setEmptyDetailedCountry={setEmptyDetailedCountry} />
  }
  else if (filteredCountries.length > 9) {
    return <FilterLengthNine setEmptyDetailedCountry={setEmptyDetailedCountry} />
  }
  else if (filteredCountries.length > 1) {
    return <FilterLengthGreaterThanOne filteredCountries={filteredCountries} buttonHandler={buttonHandler} />
  }
  else if (filteredCountries.length === 1) {
    return <FilterLengthEqualToOne filteredCountries={filteredCountries} setActualDetailedCountry={setActualDetailedCountry} />
  }
  else {
    return <></>
  }
}

const CheckDetailedDisplayConditions = ({ detailedCountry }) => {
  if (detailedCountry.length != 1) {
    console.log('no detailed country')
    return <></>
  }
  else {
    console.log('1 detailed country')
    return <Display country={detailedCountry} />
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
  const [detailedCountry, setDetailedCountry] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(response => {
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const buttonHandler = country => {
    setDetailedCountry(country);
  };

  const filterHandler = event => {
    setFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  const filterCountries = country => {
    return country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase());
  };

  const countriesSubset = countries.filter(filterCountries);

  function setEmptyDetailedCountry() {
    setDetailedCountry('')
  }

  function setActualDetailedCountry(country) {
    setDetailedCountry(country)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      find country: <input onChange={filterHandler} />
      <CheckConditions
        setEmptyDetailedCountry={setEmptyDetailedCountry}
        filteredCountries={countriesSubset}
        filter={filter}
        buttonHandler={buttonHandler}
        setActualDetailedCountry={setActualDetailedCountry} />
      <CheckDetailedDisplayConditions detailedCountry={detailedCountry} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I've been trying to learn React using this [online MOOC](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/getting_data_from_server#exercises-2-11-2-14). I'm on exercise 2.12* Data for countries, step1 and I'm stuck. My search is running fine but I'm unable to solve the last part of the problem: printing information of a selected country or if only 1 country matches the search string.

I tried debugging through console.log and it turns out that whenever I'm calling the 'setDetailedCountry' method, it's never working. My 'DetailedCountry' hook is always empty!

Please help me figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in any sandbox like codesandbox?

Comment: `useEffect`s shouldn't be _inside_ other functions.

Comment: @Andy without doing that the console throws a warning: 'Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`FilterLengthZero `). Is there some other way to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDetailedCountry` works as intended

Your `detailedCountry` doesn't have property `length` so in `CheckDetailedDisplayConditions` `detailedCountry.length != 1` always resolves as `true`

Maybe use `detailedCountry` instead

```
const CheckDetailedDisplayConditions = ({ detailedCountry }) => {
  if (!detailedCountry) {
    console.log('no detailed country')
    return <></>
  }
  else {
    console.log('1 detailed country')
    return <Display country={detailedCountry} />
  }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, do you think there's anything else I can improve in the code? I am not sure how to call functions which require attributes inside other components. The code is working but am I calling the functions correctly? For example: 
I've defined 'buttonHandler' in App and it requires an attribute. Its used further in CheckConditions -> FilterLengthGreaterThanOne -> CountryButton

Answer (score 0):

You set an object to `detailedCountry`.

```
const CheckDetailedDisplayConditions = ({ detailedCountry }) => {
  console.log("===== detailedCountry", detailedCountry);
  if (detailedCountry.length != 1) {
  ...
}
```

You can see the value of `detailedCountry` by logging its value. `detailedCountry` is not an array so you should not read the `length` value because it is always `undefined` and it is never equal to `1`. You should check whether or not it is undefined or defiend.

Comment: I thought strings have a length attribute just like in python? My bad!